# Android Adapter AlertDialog error

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have the following code inside an Adapter class I use for a listview in another class.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
builder.setTitle("Introduceti parola:");
final EditText input = new EditText(getContext());
input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
builder.setView(input);
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
    {
         hash.put("name", Rooms.name);
         hash.put("parola", input.getText().toString());
         site = siteul + "/join";
         new ATask((ViewHolder) v.getTag()).execute(site);
    }
});
builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
    }
});
builder.show();
```

The problem is that when I trigger the action I get this error at the `builder.show()` line

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

I thought the `getContext()` was at fault, but it doesn't generate any error in this code in the same Adapter class:

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Cool message!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

What could be the problem then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `getContext()` with `ActivityName.this`.

Comment: Tried it with the name of the adapter class instead of `ActivityName`, but it doesn't compile.

Comment: No, the name of the activity you need to show the window in it. Thats it, an alert is constructed with the context of an activity which it will show on.

Comment: Well, if I use that it says `ActivityName is not an enclosing class` and writing `ActivityName.class` doesn't work either.

Comment: umm :D, ActivityName should be the name of your activity.

Comment: For example, if you have a your list view activity called `MyListViewActivity`, so use `MyListViewActivity.this`.

Comment: Yes, I used that. To make sure that we are on the same page I wrote `Rooms.this`, where `Rooms` is the activity :D

Comment: And when you used `Rooms.this` it gave you a compilation error?

Comment: Yes, it said `'Rooms' is not an enclosing class`

Comment: How `Rooms` is defined? Is it an inner class? an Activity?

Comment: I created it as an Activity. Its class flie starts with `public class Rooms extends Activity`

Comment: Probably as its defined in a different file it will give you that error. I guess you can try to pass the `Rooms.this` to your adapter as a context.

Comment: So your adapter can have a constructor as `Adapter(Context cont);` and invoke it from `Rooms` as `new Adapter(Rooms.this);`.

Comment: I tried to pass the context by `getApplicationContext()` before and it didn't work, but I tried again now with `Rooms.this` and it works. Thanks!

Comment: Also another note, if your adapter is only for your `Rooms` class move it as inner class in your Activity instead of making a separate class, that keeps the abstraction and also remove the overhead of passing the context and saving it.

Comment: `getApplicationContext()` will return the application context not an activity context that will be used by the `AlertDialog` as a parent. There is a workaround to use app context, but using that of the activity is much easier and straight forward.

Comment: I've replaced `getApplicationContext()` by `MyActivity.this` and now it works.